# Maximum and Minimum numbers

Tags: java, file, max, minimum

I created file that has students scores. I got the average of each of them, but now how do I find the maximum and minimum of each test. I tried but it just prints random numbers, and ideas?Also if i wanted to print out their grades with if else statements on a new file how would I do that?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Project3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {



        ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
--

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {

    private  Formatter x;
    //Formatter variable- output string to file


    public void openFile(){
        //method to open file
        try{
            x = new Formatter("grades.txt");


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }

        public void addRecords(){
        x.format("%d",8);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", " Thui", "Bhu", 100, 90, 80, 100, 89, 99, 88);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n ArianaB", "Smith", 90, 90, 100, 100, 99, 100, 95);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Emily", "Gonzales", 100, 90, 100, 70, 78, 78, 80);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Jenifer", "L", 80, 90, 90, 100, 89, 99, 85);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Maria", "Jones", 65, 72, 77, 68, 62, 70, 65);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Bill", "Gates", 60, 54, 38, 62, 65, 60, 50);
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Escobar", "Morris", 83, 77, 88, 76, 79, 72, 76  );
        x.format(" %s %s, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", "\n Anne", "Latner", 80, 90, 85, 95, 90, 95, 90  );


        }
        public void closeFile(){
            x.close();
        }
        //



}
--

import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import java.util.*;
public class ReadFile {

private Scanner x;

        public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner (new File ("grades.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }}



ppublic void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner (new File ("grades.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }}



public void createFile()throws IOException {


    try{
        File file = new File("grades.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);


        int maxq1 =0, maxq2 =0, maxq3 =0, maxq4 =0;
        int minq1 =100, minq2 =100, minq3 = 100, minq4 =100;
        int proji_max=0, projii_max = 0, projiii_max =0;
        int proji_min =100, projii_min = 100, projiii_min =100;

    while(s.hasNext()){

        {   

        double q1average = 0.0, q2average = 0.0, q3average = 0.0, q4average = 0.0;
        double proji = 0.0, projii =0.0, projiii = 0.0;
        double q1sum = 0.0, q2sum = 0.0, q3sum = 0.0, q4sum = 0.0;
        double proji_sum = 0.0, projii_sum = 0.0, projiii_sum =0.0;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String[] split = s.nextLine().split(", ");

            q1sum += Double.parseDouble(split[1]); // add all first grades
            q1average++;

            q2sum += Double.parseDouble(split[2]); // add all first grades
            q2average++;

            q3sum += Double.parseDouble(split[3]); // add all first grades
            q3average++;

            q4sum += Double.parseDouble(split[4]); // add all first grades
            q4average++;

            proji_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[5]); // add all first grades
            proji++;

            projii_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[6]); // add all first grades
            projii++;

            projiii_sum += Double.parseDouble(split[7]); // add all first grades
            projiii++;



            if(Double.parseDouble(split[1]) > maxq1) 
                maxq1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[2]) > maxq2) 
                maxq2 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[3]) > maxq3) 
                maxq3 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[4]) > maxq4) 
                maxq4 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[5]) > proji_max) 
                proji_max = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[6]) > projii_max) 
                projii_max = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[7]) > projiii_max) 
                projiii_max = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);

            if(Double.parseDouble(split[1])< minq1) 
                   minq1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[2])< minq2) 
                   minq2 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[3])< minq3) 
                   minq3 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[3]);
            if(Double.parseDouble(split[4])< minq4) 
                minq4 = (int) Double.parseDouble(split[4]);
        }
         System.out.println(maxq2);
         System.out.println(minq2);
        double q1_average =  (q1sum/q1average);
        double q2_average = (q2sum / q2average);
        double q3_average = (q3sum / q3average);
        double q4_average = (q4sum / q4average);
        double p1_average = (proji_sum/proji);
        double p2_average = (projii_sum/projii);
        double p3_average = (projiii_sum/projiii);
    }



    }}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you reinitialise `maxq1` to 0 every time, you need to move where it's initialised before the `while` loop.

`System.out.println(maxq1);` also needs to be moved **after** the loop if you only want it to be displayed once, rather than on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: i but the int maxi =0 before the while loop, and the print after the while loop, yet i am still not getting the correct result.

Comment: I noticed you edited your OP. Is that the code as it stands now? Because I don't see maxq1 being printed anywhere now.

Comment: yes, i was checking to see if all of them work so after seeing maxq1 worked, but then I saw maxq2 just printed the first number

Comment: Before one of those `if`s, put print out to the console the two values you're comparing, and see if what you're comparing is what you're expecting. :-)

Comment: it is printing the first number and then very small numbers next to it

Comment: I'd suggest printing the values of all your splits, to see which ones you need to be using for your comparisons.

Comment: System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(split[1]) + " " + Double.parseDouble(split[2]) + " " + Double.parseDouble(split[3]) etc.

Comment: how would i get the max/min/average onto a new file that i want to create?

Answer (score 1):

Move `int maxq1 =0;` before the while loop: at the moment you are resetting it at each record...

Comment: i but the int maxi =0 before the while loop, and the print after the while loop, yet i am still not getting the correct result